# HTML5 Cache fallback

Tags: html

I am experimenting with HTML5 caching and i have stumbled onto a problem.

```
CACHE MANIFEST

/Default.aspx
/Offline.aspx
/js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js
/js/jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.min.js
/css/jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.min.css
/css/images/ajax-loader.png
/css/images/icons-18-white.png

FALLBACK:
/ Offline.aspx

NETWORK:
*
```

So my starting page is Default.aspx, when the device goes offline it should redirect to /Offline.aspx but it doesn't. Now all i can figure is because /Default.aspx is cached.
Now let's say i remove /Default.aspx from the manifest, It would still be cached because it's referencing the manifest in the HTML tag.

I have read dozens of pages concerning html caching but i can't find an answer.
Any advice would be great!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is the behavior that you should expect because if the page that references the manifest is not declared in the manifest itself (explicit), it will be considered part of the manifest implicitly as a "master" page - and from that point forward will be cached and not updated until the manifest changes.

This was not entirely clear to me either until I experienced that same behavior (in the application that I was adding offline capabilities to) and dug into the spec to better understand the observed behavior.

My solution to this was to turn the dynamic parts of that page into separate Ajax calls so that even though the page was cached (implicitly or explicitly) the parts of it that updated continued to be updated through the (non-cached) Ajax calls. However, you'll want to create fallback entries for said Ajax calls if you want them to behave nicely when offline (or handle the resulting Ajax errors if not).